# Will i be able to replace the existing application with a new application, if i'm enhancing it with more features

Tags: android, publishing

Will i be able to replace the existing application with a new application to android market, if i am enhancing it with more features

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as it is the same package and the version code is greater than the previous one. You can manage this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
....   
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.your.package"
          android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="2">

....
```

You can check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html) for reference in versioning your android app.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking here. If you're asking whether you can push an updated version of your app out to all of you're existing customers then the answer is yes.